# Mounting partition LVM in server

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

Installed server with 1TB hdd. Server created a logical volume for the boot.

[image]

[image]

This is the only logical volume right now

[image]

Need help with next steps to mount the remaining 730GB to some location.

I tried to do `lvcreate -L 730G other` but was getting `missing NTFS signature`

Comment: Solved. used this https://www.tecklyfe.com/how-to-expand-an-lvm-disk-in-ubuntu-linux/.

Answer (score 0):

instead of re-partitioning; just resized the existing partition. Some steps:

- sudo fdisk -l
- pvresize /dev/sda3
- lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
- resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv